# Why navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() returns different values?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I'm trying to use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` in my app, but the values that I'm getting are different in other tabs of Chrome browser (Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (x86_64)) on macOS.

I have an app where values are correct:

```
(6) [InputDeviceInfo, InputDeviceInfo, MediaDeviceInfo, MediaDeviceInfo, MediaDeviceInfo, MediaDeviceInfo]
0: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: "default", kind: "audioinput", label: "Default - Internal Microphone (Built-in)", groupId: "c94bbcbb837464efa2be6befae9af57071548deadbaa65858734e6ec195b13e5"}
1: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: "1cc1945e5003a2e0719d7dd5d8a608751d736931f5b4717779477b81de639cc7", kind: "audioinput", label: "Internal Microphone (Built-in)", groupId: "c94bbcbb837464efa2be6befae9af57071548deadbaa65858734e6ec195b13e5"}
2: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: "default", kind: "audiooutput", label: "Default - Headphones (Built-in)", groupId: "c94bbcbb837464efa2be6befae9af57071548deadbaa65858734e6ec195b13e5"}
3: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: "e7a1915585026f90deec4ec0c8f6b80e9501d024383f6b57e39b66459e84e16f", kind: "audiooutput", label: "Headphones (Built-in)", groupId: "c94bbcbb837464efa2be6befae9af57071548deadbaa65858734e6ec195b13e5"}
4: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: "4b226402572bc2af31811f5420c82ab7d28e957a2972e1505060cbdcd4f349c0", kind: "audiooutput", label: "DELL U2719D (DisplayPort)", groupId: "a4fbcbab8bae9811e123536d0ab9ea28a9179aed6439209ec74a08ba3b978da0"}
5: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: "c1e379faea073a3dc9e6ad3a69c2b7ef9e186b3faa1194f454cdc9ae1cb8aa80", kind: "audiooutput", label: "DELL U2719D (DisplayPort)", groupId: "7a20b5af20e078ebff0a2ee7d0412c9cce78be62378c22e492380ff201ac0a63"}
```

But if you switch to another tab with another domain (but with production version of my app) or even to chrome://newtab I'm getting:

```
0: InputDeviceInfo
deviceId: ""
groupId: "44b72fddafb7c5df78739a1b773a7842214a620402bca6537a545dd3e1df7424"
kind: "audioinput"
label: ""
__proto__: InputDeviceInfo
1: MediaDeviceInfo
deviceId: ""
groupId: "44b72fddafb7c5df78739a1b773a7842214a620402bca6537a545dd3e1df7424"
kind: "audiooutput"
label: ""
```

What can be the cause of this behavior? I'm not even using those devices and the tab with my app is closed when I'm getting the second result.

Answer (score 2):

If you see an empty deviceId it means that you didn't have granted permissions for it. Use `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` for it.